# Possible beginner Python installation causing errors when trying to install anything with pip on OSX 10.9

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

I have been trying to solve this problem for 5 hours now with no luck.

I installed python 3.3 earlier today and then learned through google searches that twisted does not currently work/install with this version of python on mac.

However, none of the above should matter because my default version of python is set to 2.7.5 and I know this because when I type Python into the terminal it outputs this:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
```

Here's the problem though. Whenever I type "pip install scrapy" or "pip install twisted" into the terminal I get the same output at the end that says 2 warnings and 6 errors have been generated.

And when I look at the terminal output it constantly references version 3.3 of python. Nowhere does it say anything about the correct default version of 2.7.5.

Here's a small sample of what the terminal outputs when I try to install scrapy with pip (Notice how it only references python 3.3):

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scrapy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages
Downloading/unpacking Twisted>=10.0.0 (from scrapy)
  Downloading Twisted-13.2.0.tar.bz2 (2.7MB): 2.7MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/sj/fs5lzbyd7p37_jdkqw03_q4c0000gn/T/pip_build_patrickjohnson/Twisted/setup.py) egg_info for package Twisted

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): w3lib>=1.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/w3lib-1.5-py3.3.egg (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): queuelib in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/queuelib-1.1.1-py3.3.egg (from scrapy)
```

So am I correct in assuming that my pip installs are failing because for some reason they are trying to utilize version 3.3 of python when really they should be using version 2.7.5?

Why is this happening if my default is clearly set to 2.7.5?

Comment: try using pip-2.7 instead of pip.

Comment: I'm new with the terminal. Do you mean enter in "pip-2.7 install scrapy" ? Because that outputs command not found.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. I was using virtualenv but was still entering in "pip install scrapy" when I needed to enter in "NameOfVirtualEnv/bin/pip install scrapy"

Answer (score 0):

> So am I correct in assuming that my pip installs are failing because
>   for some reason they are trying to utilize version 3.3 of python when
>   really they should be using version 2.7.5?

I think your issue is just the opposite. when you installed python3.3 on your mac you did not override your old version of python2.7.  in terminal, when you type `python` you should enter your system's default version of python, version 2.7.  Should you want to use version 3.3, entering `python3.3` should cause you to enter that version.  I'm assuming that pip is installed on your python2.7, and because 2.7 is in a higher directory, you have to run `sudo pip install` instead of `pip install`. if the packages still don't work, you can check out my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430463/installing-python-packages-with-multiple-versions-on-osx) as i've still been unable to understand why my version doesn't recognize packages.  hope this helps.